# swapon /dev/sda3 : swapon failed : device or resource busy

Tags: swap

i've just switched from XP to ubuntu, and i've made some partitions, like efi, /home, swap, and root. For me it is pretty good OS, but when i checked the partition, i noticed that the swap partition on the off condition, so i tried to activate it, and then this message showed up ; swapon failed : device or resource busy. So, what does it mean by that? hope can find help for this question

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/688627/swapon-failed-device-or-resource-busy-on-mounted-disk#747752) answer on serverfault worked for me:

```
#: swapoff /dev/sda2
#: mkswap /dev/sda2
#: swapon /dev/sda2enter code here
```

Then check it with

```
#: lsblk
```